# How to avoid freeze while scrape from CME webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from CME but the code seems to freeze at `requests.get()` function.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/interest-rates/us-treasury/2-year-us-treasury-note.settlements.html'
page = requests.get(URL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that they are checking for `user-agent`

> The User-Agent request header is a characteristic string that lets servers and network peers identify the application, operating system, vendor, and/or version of the requesting user agent.

*Not a specific one, so just give them your favorite agent*:

```
requests.get(URL, headers={'user-agent':'SALT'}).text
```

More about `user-agent` check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: How did you know this was the issue? Is there way to get an error message in this case?

Comment: Good question - In this case it is an empirical value, there was no explicit error message for it. In general, it is a good approach to orient your requests as closely as possible to how your browser assembles them, because content can also be delivered differently based on them.